# Can install BIDS 2008 on local machine and link to SQL 2008 on another server?

Tags: sql-server-2008, bids

Can I install BIDS 2008 on local machines and have it hook up to SQL Server 2008 on another server?  We can remote into the server but are trying to stop having people constatnly on the server working on SSRS reports.

So is it possible to install on a local machine and create and deploy reports from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. you can install  BIDS and create-deploy reports in server from there.

please take a look at the link below- hope, it'll help you.

[Sql-Server-reporting-services-getting-started](http://www.datasprings.com/resources/articles-information/sql-server-reporting-services-getting-started)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the stand alone [Report Builder 2.0](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=9829) if it suits your requirements. It is a more lightweight application tailored for report building.